# Como hacer un query con like que tenga un backslash

Tags: mysql

Quiero filtrar `"Creaci\\u00f3n"`

```
SELECT * FROM database.tabla where columna like "%Creaci\\u00f3n%";
```

como podría hacerlo??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el símbolo \ es el carácter de escape en `mysql`.

El [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html) lo aclara en su documentación.

> Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to
>   represent a newline character), you must double any “\” that you use
>   in LIKE strings. For example, to search for “\n”, specify it as “\n”.
>   To search for “\”, specify it as “\\\\”; this is because the
>   backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern
>   match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.
>
> Como Mysql usa la sintaxis de C para escapar caracteres (por ejemplo
>   "\n" para representar una nueva linea), hay que doblar cualquier "\"
>   que se usa en strings dentro de like. Por ejemplo para busar "\n" hay
>   que especificar "\n". Para buscar "\", hay que especificarlo como
>   "\\\\"; esto es porque las barras invertidas son descopuestas una
>   vez por el parser y luego cuando se trata de igualar, dejando como si
>   hubiera una sola barra invertida.

Entonces, en este caso, como necesitas que haya dos barras invertidas, vas a tener que escribir 8 (si, 8), o aclarar que vas a usar otro caracter de escape.

Tus opciones son:

```
SELECT * FROM database.tabla where columna like "%Creaci\\\\\\\\u00f3n%";
```

o (algo que parece mejor):

```
SELECT * FROM database.tabla where columna like "%Creaci\\u00f3n%" ESCAPE '|';
```

Esta ultima le dice que usas como carácter de escape |.